# Reset Activity Every Time it Launches

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I am trying to reset an activity every time it is called, so that it is called as though it has not been opened in this app session. Here is what I have tried

I tried this in the manifest

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

And then I tried this with intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

But none of these work? How can I set it so that it is as though this is the first time the activity is being launch?

Thanks

Comment: try intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

Comment: @galvan when I hit the back button now I exit the app?